# Could async methods that change the same value be a concurrency problem in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, concurrency, firebase-storage

I am using *Firebase Storage* to get images in my app. So I am getting the image name from the database and setting up the download link with it.

I want to load the image url only once in the whole app. So I created a provider with a map like so **{imageName: imageUrl}**.

If the map contains a key with the `imageName`, means that the `imageUrl` was already loaded and doesn't need to be loaded again.

The question is: Would it be a problem if two async methods try to save the same `imageName` with `imageUrl` in the map at the same time?

Code to simulate the case:

Provider

```
class ImagesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map imagesUrlsMap= {};

  loadImage({required String imageName}) async {
    try {
      if(imagesUrlsMap[imageName] == null) {
        /// Load image url
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        /// imageUrl comes from internet
        const imageUrl = 'https://imageDownloadUrl.com';
        imagesUrlsMap[imageName] = imageUrl;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Image Widget

```
class WidgetThatRequiresImageUrl extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetThatRequiresImageUrl({Key? key, required this.imageName}) : super(key: key);

  final String imageName;

  @override
  State<WidgetThatRequiresImageUrl> createState() => _WidgetThatRequiresImageUrlState();
}

class _WidgetThatRequiresImageUrlState extends State<WidgetThatRequiresImageUrl> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final dataProvider = context.read<ImagesProvider>();
    dataProvider.loadImage(imageName: widget.imageName);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ImagesProvider>(
      builder: (context, dataProvider, _) {
        final imageUrl = dataProvider.imagesUrlsMap[widget.imageName];
        return imageUrl == null ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : Image.network(imageUrl);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Using it multiple times

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          WidgetThatRequiresImageUrl(imageName: 'Name'),
          WidgetThatRequiresImageUrl(imageName: 'Name'),
          WidgetThatRequiresImageUrl(imageName: 'Name'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the main

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ImagesProvider(),
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because a single isolate is effectively single-threaded as far as the user is concerned. (There are actually multiple threads, mostly to handle some I/O and some garbage collection, but those are transparent to the app.) Now, if you're running multiple Isolates (WebWorkers on the web), you can have parallel execution, but those are then share-nothing, so again, you can't be accessing the same thing more than once.

Comment: Just because a single isolate is single-threaded does not mean that there cannot be concurrency problems.  There wouldn't be a problem in the sense of having undefined or indeterminate behavior from multiple threads reading and writing the same value, but there could be a problem that the code would be not behave as intended when asynchronous calls are interleaved.  For example, multiple calls to `loadImage` with the same argument can result in multiple executions of the `// Load image url` block even though the intent (most likely) is to perform that once and to cache the result.

Comment: But those would be happening in separate Isolates, so yes, multiple fetches would be made from the source, but the results would not be *broken* in the receivers, just *inefficient*.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by separate `Isolate`s.  You could have multiple outstanding calls to `loadImage` from the same `Isolate`.  And yes, I agree that in this particular case, there's no real harm other than being inefficient.